# str_replace all in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to replace all values that I have in a field called age and a table called screens
the field has rows that contain numbers with a plus sign

> like age= 15+

I am trying to remove all the + signs 
so do an update that will change all fields
for example if fields are

> 18+ 21+ 45+

change them to : 18 21 and 45

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into the SQL `UPDATE ... WHERE` syntax at all?

Comment: sure I know about it but I dont know about string replace function for sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE screens SET age= REPLACE(age, '+', '');
```

Comment: thank you Shakti, can I return results without the + sign ? for example if the field contains "15+" I want to return results between 10 and 16. that would include it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure of your data, but this will select all the numbers without *any* + signs:

```
select replace(age, '+', '') from screens
```

You can obviously use that in an UPDATE.